# How to use document.body.appendChild to add in html row

Tags: javascript, jsom

I am very new to programming , And I had written the code to create the "input control" . And I am able to make it , 
But I need to place the input control in html table row  "txtHTML = txtHTML + "Place the created input control here" + "";

can any one please help me how can I do it

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 <table id="tblCustomListData" border="1" width="100%" style="overflow-x:auto;">
              <thead>
                     <tr class="bgcolorgray">
                        <th>Sno</th>
                        <th >Current DR</th>
                     </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
</div >
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



function myFunction() {


var txtHTML = "";
$('#tblCustomListData tbody').html('');


var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
x.setAttribute("value", "Hello!");
document.body.appendChild(x);



  txtHTML = txtHTML + "<tr>";
     txtHTML = txtHTML + "<td>";
     txtHTML = txtHTML + "Place the created input control here"+ "</a>";
     txtHTML = txtHTML + "</td>";
  txtHTML = txtHTML + "</tr>";

  $("#tblCustomListData").append(txtHTML);

  }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not the correct forum for a basic coding question.  You need to explain how this relates to Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like a SharePoint-related question, but still. I've modified your code a bit:

```
<button id='tryItButton' >Try it</button>
<table id="tblCustomListData" border="1" width="100%" style="overflow-x:auto;">
          <thead>
                 <tr class="bgcolorgray">
                    <th>Sno</th>
                    <th >Current DR</th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  document.getElementById ("tryItButton").addEventListener ("click", myFunction, false);
  function myFunction() {
    $('#tblCustomListData tbody').html('');
    var txtHTML =  `<tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' id='uniqueIdentifier' value='hello' />
                    </td>
                </tr>`;

  $("#tblCustomListData").append(txtHTML);

  }
});

</script>
```